# How to programmatically detect if an object is a jQuery object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I programmatically detect if an object is a jQuery object? For example:

```
// 1. declare some variables
var vars = [1, 'hello', ['bye', 3], $(body), { say: 'hi' }];

// 2. ??? : implement function that tests whether its parameter is a jQuery object
function isjQuery(arg) { /* ??? */ }

// 3. profit
var test = $.map(vars, isjQuery); /* expected [ false, false, false, true, false ] */
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can rely on

```
if ( vars[i] instanceof jQuery ) {
  // do something with this jQuery object
}
```

but I also found these methods [here](http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-en/browse_thread/thread/9889375a2d0b81a4):

```
obj && obj.constructor == jQuery 
obj && obj.jquery
```

Answer (score 9):

The easiest API-documented way is to test for the [`.jquery`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery-2/) property:

```
function isjQuery(arg) {
    return !!arg.jquery;
}
```

However, if you want to be **sure** it's a jQuery object and not some other object with a fake `.jquery` property, the other answers suggesting `instanceof jQuery` and testing the constructor work too.

(The [`.jquery`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery-2/) property is formally a string indicating the jQuery version, but the API example uses it to test whether an object is a jQuery object.)

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways, but the clearest (in my opinion) would be:

```
function isjQuery(arg) { return arg instanceof jQuery; }
```